# Determining input shape for tensorflow keras LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm having a bit of trouble with this. To start off, here is what my data is like:

test_data, test_labels, train_data, train_labels

```
train_data[0]

[1, 5, 5, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 25, 1, 1, 10, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 39, 2, 0, 1, 1, 12, 3]

train_labels[0]

0
```

It's the exact same for test_data and test_labels (it's just a 50/50 split of input data). The array size for each array in test_data will always be 25 elements. The label is either 0 for good or 1 for bad.

Now, I've tried lot's of things so far and can't come up with how to reshape these arrays. I'm essentially trying to do this:

```
    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(256, input_shape=unknown, return_sequences=False, return_state=False, dropout=0.2))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
    history = self.model.fit(self.train_data,
                             self.train_labels,
                             epochs=50,
                             batch_size=64,
                             verbose=1,
                             validation_split=0.2)
```

Another question, is 2 correct for the last dense layer, or should it be 1 in this case?

Comment: What are your input features? What are you trying to predict?

Comment: Malicious URLs. There are 25 different attributes, things like domain length, number of delimiters, dictionary words, etc.

Comment: Ok. It seems like these attributes are not "temporal". Why do you want to use an LSTM?

Comment: Was trying to recreate an example I saw that was using one. What would you recommend instead? I know I could probably do a random forest. My dataset is fairly large compared to other examples (1,500,000 urls)

Comment: Yeah, I believe an LSTM does not make sense here. A random forest or a feedforward network might be more appropriate